# Android uri not works on on 6.0 above device how to fixed it?

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

Hello friend i am working mp3 player     my          Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///"+song.getGetpath()); works fine on 6.0 device but its not workin  6.0 above device how to fixed using fileprovider i dont  know to use how to use fileprovider i am beginner please help here my uri parse code my all audio file is in my phone device
and it return null param cannot be null
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///"+song.getGetpath());

```
here my class code

  package music.playerforandroid;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.Manifest;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.AudioVisualization;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.VisualizerDbmHandler;
import com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout;
import static music.playerforandroid.App.CHANNEL_ID_1;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ListView songView;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;
    Song song;
    private SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingLayout;
    Context mContext;
    private Utilities utils;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000;
    private AudioVisualization audioVisualization;
    private VisualizerDbmHandler handler;
    int postion;
    int totalduration;
    int totalTime;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    Uri uri;
    ImageView rotate;
    private long currentsongLength;
    TextView elapsedTimeLabel, remainingTimeLabel;
    TextView title, artist;
    ImageView playchange;
    ImageButton like, notlike, dislike, notdislike, next, pervious, repeat, reaptenable;
    ImageButton play, pause, play_main, pause_main, shuffle, shufflenable;
    private SlidingUpPanelLayout mLayout;
    private boolean isShuffle;
    private boolean checked;
    private NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManagerCompat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        songView = findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        artist = findViewById(R.id.artist);
        title = findViewById(R.id.songname);

        elapsedTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.songtime);
        remainingTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.endTime);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
        next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        pervious = findViewById(R.id.pervious);
        like = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        notlike = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2new);
        dislike = findViewById(R.id.button);
        notdislike = findViewById(R.id.buttontwo);
        play = findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        repeat = findViewById(R.id.repeat);
        reaptenable = findViewById(R.id.repeatenable);
        pause = findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        play_main = findViewById(R.id.play_button_main);
        pause_main = findViewById(R.id.pause_button_main);
        like = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        notlike = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2new);
        dislike = findViewById(R.id.button);
        notdislike = findViewById(R.id.buttontwo);
        play = findViewById(R.id.play_button);

        pause = findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        shuffle = findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
        shufflenable = findViewById(R.id.shufflenable);
        elapsedTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.endTime);
        remainingTimeLabel = findViewById(R.id.songtime);
        play_main = findViewById(R.id.play_button_main);
        pause_main = findViewById(R.id.pause_button_main);
        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        rotate = findViewById(R.id.rotate);
        audioVisualization = findViewById(R.id.visualizer_view);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        utils = new Utilities();
        mNotificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        getSongList();
        Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
            public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
            }
        });

        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long id) {

                play(position);


            }
        });


        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals("music.playerforandroid.ACTION_PAUSE_MUSIC")) {

                    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        rotate.clearAnimation();
                    }
                    pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song is Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (pause_main.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        pause_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        play_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                } else if (action.equals("music.playerforandroid.ACTION_PLAY_MUSIC")) {

                    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                        play(0);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();

                        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Is now Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (play_main.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            play_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pause_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Animation aniRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
                            rotate.startAnimation(aniRotate);
                        }
                    }


                } else if (action.equals("music.playerforandroid.NEXT_PLAY_MUSIC")) {
                    if (currentSongIndex < (songList.size() - 1)) {
                        play(currentSongIndex + 1);
                        currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                    } else {
                        // play first song
                        play(0);
                        currentSongIndex = 0;
                    }
                } else if (action.equals("music.playerforandroid.PERVIOUS_PLAY_MUSIC")) {

                    if (currentSongIndex > 0) {
                        play(currentSongIndex - 1);
                        currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                    } else {
                        // play last song
                        play(songList.size() - 1);
                        currentSongIndex = songList.size() - 1;
                    }

                }


            }
        };


        repeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                repeat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                reaptenable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                shuffle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                shufflenable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isShuffle = false;
                checked = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        reaptenable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                repeat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                reaptenable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                checked = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });

        shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                reaptenable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                checked = false;
                isShuffle = true;

                shuffle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                shufflenable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isShuffle = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        shufflenable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shuffle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                shufflenable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notlike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Like the Song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (notdislike.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    notdislike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });


        notlike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        dislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notdislike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You DisLike the Song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (notlike.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    notlike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });


        notdislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notdislike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    play(0);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

                play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Is now Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (play_main.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    play_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Animation aniRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
                    rotate.startAnimation(aniRotate);
                }

            }
        });

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                    mediaPlayer.pause();

                    rotate.clearAnimation();
                }
                pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song is Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (pause_main.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    pause_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    play_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });


        play_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    play(0);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

                play_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Is now Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (play.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Animation aniRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
                    rotate.startAnimation(aniRotate);
                }
            }
        });


        pervious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentSongIndex > 0) {
                    play(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                } else {
                    // play last song
                    play(songList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songList.size() - 1;
                }
                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (currentSongIndex < (songList.size() - 1)) {
                            play(currentSongIndex + 1);
                            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                        } else {
                            // play first song
                            play(0);
                            currentSongIndex = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        });

        pause_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                pause_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                play_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song is Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (pause.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rotate.clearAnimation();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mLayout != null &&
                (mLayout.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED || mLayout.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED)) {
            mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);


        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
        public void getSongList() {
            //retrieve song info
            ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
            if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                //get columns
                int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                int dataColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


                //add songs to list
                do {
                    long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                    String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                    String thisPath = musicCursor.getString(dataColumn);

                    songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisPath));
                }
                while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        public void play(int songindex) {
            song = songList.get(songindex);

            try {

                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }


                //file:///" + song.getGetpath()








               // final Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "myprovider", new File(song.getGetpath()));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///"+song.getGetpath());

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,    uri);




                title.setText(song.getTitle());
                artist.setText(song.getArtist());

                show();




                handler = VisualizerDbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(getApplicationContext(), mediaPlayer);
                audioVisualization.linkTo(handler);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                seekBar.setProgress(0);            seekBar.setMax(100);
                updateProgressBar();

                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    play_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Animation aniRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
                    rotate.startAnimation(aniRotate);

                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


                            if (checked) {
                                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            } else if (isShuffle) {
                                // shuffle is on - play a random song
                                Random rand = new Random();
                                currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                                play(currentSongIndex);
                            } else {
                                // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
                                if (currentSongIndex < (songList.size() - 1)) {
                                    play(currentSongIndex + 1);
                                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                                } else {
                                    // play first song
                                    play(0);
                                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        }


    public void forward() {

        int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
        if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
            // forward song
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
        } else {
            // forward to end position
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        }
    }
    public void backword() {

        int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
        if (currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0) {
            // forward song
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
        } else {
            // backward to starting position
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            // Displaying Total Duration time
            remainingTimeLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            // Displaying time completed playing
            elapsedTimeLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

            // Updating progress bar
            int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
            //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("music.playerforandroid.ACTION_PAUSE_MUSIC");
        intentFilter.addAction("music.playerforandroid.ACTION_PLAY_MUSIC");
        intentFilter.addAction("music.playerforandroid.NEXT_PLAY_MUSIC");
        intentFilter.addAction("music.playerforandroid.PERVIOUS_PLAY_MUSIC");
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
    }

    public  void show(){
        Bitmap largeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.musicicon);

        PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, new Intent("music.playerforandroid.ACTION_PAUSE_MUSIC"), 0);
        PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, new Intent("music.playerforandroid.ACTION_PLAY_MUSIC"), 0);
        PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, new Intent("music.playerforandroid.NEXT_PLAY_MUSIC"), 0);
        PendingIntent perviousPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, new Intent("music.playerforandroid.PERVIOUS_PLAY_MUSIC"), 0);
        Notification channel = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID_1)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music)
                .setContentTitle(song.getTitle())
                .setContentText(song.getArtist())
                .setLargeIcon(largeImage)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "prev", perviousPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_play, "play", playPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_name, "pause", pausePendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "next", nextPendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().
                        setShowActionsInCompactView(1, 2, 3))
                .build();
        mNotificationManagerCompat.notify(1, channel);
        }


}
```

Comment: What is the error the you are getting? Can you post that?

Comment: Hello Surabhi Choudhary it return null java.Nullpointer.Exception contex param cannot be null while its work fine below 7.0 devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Context` is null.

Try changing

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, uri);
```

to

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had thiss problem before, it happens because `MediaPlayer.create(...)` method returns null object when failed to create, so you have to keep checking if it's null:

```
do {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,    uri);
    } while (mediaPlayer == null);
```

or use another method: `mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()` ,then `setDataSource(...)` ,then prepare and start.

Comment: Yes this is correct, you should check if the player is not null, but he's `mContext` is null because he never initialised it, he sets `Context mContext` and that's all.

Comment: @mahasongs It might means that creation process was successful: if you are sure it will be successful always on 6,0 you can add a condition statement concerning android version below 6,0

Comment: @HB. Yeah it seems right. you can post it as an answer to solve this. I will keep mine here for anyone else.